# Properties of Spectral Transformations - Allocation (decomposition into even and odd part)

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier

I am trying to understand the Allocation property of Spectral Transformations. I can't.

I know that every function can be separated into an even part and into an odd part.

My problem is understanding proof for that:

$$s(t)=s_e(t)+s_o(t)$$
where:

- $s_e(t)$ - even part of function
- $s_o(t)$ - odd part of function

The problem is that in next step at every site I looked so far, it goes something like this:

$$s_e(t) =\dfrac{s(t)+s(-t)}{2}$$

Why did they do this? Where did $\frac{1}{2}$ come from, and why is $s(t)+s(-t)$

Can you please explain it to me, or point me to a good resource where I could read more about it?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that your signal is composed of two parts: even and odd:

$$s(t)=s_e(t)+s_o(t)$$

We also know following properties of this type of functions:

- Even: $f(-x)=f(x)$
- Odd:  $f(-x)=-f(x)$

Let's calculate the time inversion of your signal $s(-t)$ and apply above properties:

$$s(-t)=s_e(-t)+s_o(-t)=s_e(t)-s_o(t) $$

So now let's do the trick and add the: $s(t)$ and $s(-t)$:

$$\require{cancel} s(t)+s(-t) = \color{blue}{s_e(t)}+ \cancel{\color{red}{s_o(t)}} + \color{blue}{s_e(t)}-\cancel{\color{red}{s_o(t)}}=\color{blue}{2s_e(t)} $$

Solve it for $\color{blue}{s_e(t)}$, and you will get:

$$\boxed{\color{blue}{s_e(t)}=\dfrac{s(t)+s(-t)}{2}} $$

In the end let's subtract $s(t)$ and $s(-t)$:

$$s(t)-s(-t) = \cancel{\color{blue}{s_e(t)}} + \color{red}{s_o(t)} - \cancel{\color{blue}{s_e(t)}} + \color{red}{s_o(t)}=\color{red}{2s_o(t)} $$

Rearrange and you will get:

$$\boxed{\color{red}{s_o(t)}=\dfrac{s(t)-s(-t)}{2}} $$

Comment: Aren't you _assuming_ that the signal $s(t)$ _can_ be expressed as the sum of an even function $s_e(t)$ and an odd function $s_o(t)$ which is _exactly_ what needs to be _proved?_

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Can't see anything wrong with this answer. OP want's to understand how come $s_e(t)=\frac{s(t)+s(-t)}{2}$, is that right? Hence simple and correct explanation. If you want proof then you can always refer for example to [this post](http://mrhonner.com/archives/8957) (in fact reasoning is basically the same). Most important part is to use the properties of odd and even functions - rest is only juggling with variables.

Comment: Errr no, in the proof that you link to, the author first _constructs_ the signals $s_e(t)$ and $s_o(t)$ from the given $s(t)$, shows that their sum is $s(t)$, and then _proves_ that $s_e(t)$ is even and $s_o(t)$ is odd. He then also proves that the decomposition of $s(t)$ into the sum of an even function and an odd function is unique. Even ignoring this last part as unnecessary nitpicking, that is a reasonable proof. You begin in the middle by assuming that $s(t)$ _is_ the sum of an even and an odd function (which is to be proved) and then show how the two functions are related to $s(t)$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I would like you to answer once again for my first question. Because in my opinion it is 'no'. After all I didn't noticed any word 'proof' in my post (do you?) - it is **explanation**.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have available to you $s(t)$ as a known function of time.  What this is means is that if I ask you what if the value of $s(t)$ when, say,
$t = 1.23$, you can provide me with the value, say $4.56$ which is
conventionally written as $s(1.23) = 4.56$. But there is nothing magical about
$1.23$. I can choose *any* real number value for $t$ and you are able to tell
me what the value of $s$ is at that point in time.

So, now I ask you for the values of $s(1.23)$ and $s(-1.23)$, and the values
of $s(4.56)$ and $(-4.56)$ etc. until you are sick and tired of answering
my questions, and build for myself *two* functions that I
name as $s_e(t)$ and $s_o(t)$. Their values are as follows:
$$\begin{align}
s_e(1.23) &= \frac{s(1.23) + s(-1.23)}{2}\\
s_e(4.56) &= \frac{s(4.56) + s(-4.56)}{2}\\
\end{align}$$
and, more generally
$\displaystyle \qquad\qquad \qquad \quad  s_e(t) = \frac{s(t) + s(-t)}{2}\quad$ for **each and every** value of $t$.
Similarly,$\displaystyle \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \qquad \quad  s_o(t) = \frac{s(t) - s(-t)}{2}\quad$ for **each and every** value of $t$.
That bold-faced stuff is important: I can apply the definition even
when $t$ is a negative number: there is nothing in the definition
that requires that $t$ be a positive number because there is no $-$ 
sign in front of it in the formula. It is perfectly OK for $t$ to
be $-1.23$ and $-t = 1.23$ in the formula.

These functions that I have built for myself, and which you could build
for yourself too, have the following interesting properties. I know that
$$s_e(1.23) = \frac{s(1.23) + s(-1.23)}{2}.$$
But,
$$s_e(-1.23) = \frac{s(-1.23) + s(1.23)}{2} = s_e(1.23)$$ and more
generally, $s_e(t) = s_e(-t)$ for **all** values of $t$.  In other
words, $s_e(t)$ is an **even** function of $t$. Similarly, it can
be shown that $s_o(t)$ is an **odd** function of $t$.

Now that I have built my functions, I tell you about them and say
"Hey, lookit, these functions that I just made up have a very
special property:
$$\text{For each and every value of} ~~t, ~s(t) = s_e(t)+s_o(t).
~~\text{Isn't that interesting?"}$$