# Show that any continuous-time signal $x(t)$ can be represented as $x(t)= x_e(t) + x_o(t)$

Tags: continuous-signals

Show that any continuous-time signal $x(t)$ can be represented as $x(t)= x_e(t) + x_o(t)$

where $x_e(t) =\frac{1}{2}[x(t) + x(-t)]$ and $x_o(t) = \frac{1}{2}
[x(t) − x(-t)]$
are even and odd functions, respectively.

Comment: Welcome on DSP SE Michael, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Gilles Nothing...sorry for my weak math foundation, i don't know how to start it.   Maybe you can give a direction to me first so i can try to do something....

Comment: You are trying to show that the equation is true. Perhaps you should try to see what happens if you plug the expressions given for $x_e(t)$ and $x_o(t)$ to it.

Comment: @hulappa i tried that,x(t)=1/2 x(t)*2 = x(t) So this is the answer?  Is that simple? Maybe i thought too complicated ....

Comment: [This](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/16831/8202) and [this](http://mrhonner.com/archives/8957) might be useful to you.

Comment: @jojek thank you for the sources so i know any function can be expressed as an even and odd function now. Then,for my question, it is already given that xe() =1/2[() + (−)] and () = 1/2 [() − (−)]  and they are even and odd function. Except adding them together, I don't know what i can show.

Comment: Hint: you have two equations with two unknowns x(t) and x(-t). Solve for x(t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute the last two equations into the first and it should be clear.

iI.e., if you have $x_e(t), x_o(t)$  given to you. Substitute these into the equation for $x(t)$ and you should see that both sides are equal to each other.

(Note that this proves the equality, but doesn't prove that $x_e(t)$ is even or that $x_o(t)$ is odd.)

Comment: we **define** $x_e(t)$ to be even symmetry, i.e. $$x_e(-t)=x_e(t)$$  we define that. and we define $x_o(t)$ to be odd symmetry, to wit: $$x_o(-t)=-x_o(t)$$.  then we posit that $$x(t) = x_e(t) + x_o(t)$$ and then ask, for that to be true, what must $x_e(t)$ and $x_o(t)$ be?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson this is good to know, but I don't think the original question requires this proof. I just put that last part in as a throwaway line